# How can I parse the script code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parser

How do I parse the script tag or script URL I specified?

As a result of the parse operation, I will be able to obtain the script global variables and functions within the object. it should be able to show the default values of the variables.

#### Example

```
// Input

var a = 5;

function b(){}

var c = function(){
        var d=1;
};
```

#### Result

```
// Output
{
   "a":{
      "type":"variable",
      "value":5
   },
   "b":{
      "type":"function",
      "type":"void"
   },
   "c":{
      "type":"function",
      "type":"void",
      "scope":{
         "d":{
            "type":"variable",
            "value":1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Is there a library that will work like the example above?**

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want a Javascript library to parse Javascript code?

Comment: @Alejandro I want to know is what people do to parse javascript code. library etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITNOA

as you can see in [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2554519/1539100) many library have this, for example

- [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)
- [Esprima](https://esprima.org/)
- [acorn](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API

Comment: What is ITNOA ?